# Dream weaver not allwoing .class files to open

Tags: dreamweaver

How to open .class file in dream weaver cs3

Thanks in advance,
shanker

Comment: .class? that is a compiled java code! it doesn't open in DW, do yuo mean a CSS?

Comment: Actually i am using a code base which has .class files. The file contains php code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, right click a .class file, choose "Open with", and then browse to DreamWeaver, maybe tick "Always open with this program"... So easy!

Answer (score 0):

There actually is one "hack" that allows you to open class files in Dreamweaver.

If you use Dreamweaver's search feature, which searches files and you have the extensions.txt set for class files, then Dreamweaver will search the class file and return results. After that you can now double click the result and it will open the class file in Dreamweaver. It is the only place Adobe has forgotten to disable in order to open class files.